# Python Pandas - When using read_excel or csv is it possible to convert data type by referencing the column number?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am bringing in a large dataset from an Excel file to a python pandas dataframe. At present I am referencing each column by name but as I have 30 or so columns this is quite inefficient. See sample code below:

```
df=pd.read_excel(Filename, converters={'Business date':str, 'Member Name':str, 'Account':str,  'Currency': str, 'Amount':float})
```

Would it be possible to instead reference columns 0 to 4 as string then 5 as float etc up to 30?

Comment: Doesn't Pandas automatically read floats as floats and strings as strings? Converters are, afaik, only required for more heavy-handed tasks.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `df.read_excel` will try to intelligently guess the dtype for each
column.  It guesses based on the values in the first few rows. You only need to
use the `converters` parameter if `df.read_excel` fails to guess the dtypes correctly.

---

The `converters` parameter can accept a dict whose keys are either column names *or ordinal index numbers*. Per [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
converters : dict, default None

    Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can
    either be integers or column labels, values are functions that take one
    input argument, the Excel cell content, and return the transformed
    content.
```

---

To construct the desired dict without having to type all 31 entries, you could use a dict comprehension:

```
In [146]: dict((i,str) if i < 5 else (i,float) for i in range(31))
Out[149]: 
{0: str,
 1: str,
 2: str,
 3: str,
 4: str,
 5: float,
 ...
 30: float}
```

Thus you could use:

```
converters = dict((i,str) if i < 5 else (i,float) for i in range(31))
df = pd.read_excel(filename, converters=converters)
```

---

Each `converter` function is called once for every value in the column. That can
be a lot of function calls, and bad for performance.

Therefore, a quicker alternative is to read in the entire dataframe as strings and then use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to convert certain columns to floats:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype=str)
df.iloc[:, 5:] = df.iloc[:, 5:].astype(float)
```